How to resolve python paths to import all necessary modules?
Running the command "sudo /bin/python3 program.py" results in python paths like "/usr/local/bin."  Running the command "sudo bin/python3 program.py" results in python paths to my virtual environment.  So the two have different python paths.
The result of this is that the first command allows me to import the wiringpi module needed to access the GPIO pins of an orangepi.  Running the second command allows me to import adafruit modules I need to control various devices.
I installed the "wiringOP-Python" package that includes the wiringpi module into the virtual environment under "/venv/bin/" but I still can't get both the wiringpi modules and the adafruit modules to be imported through the same python library.

You should avoid running your script with sudo. Can you [edit] and be more specific? Where is which library installed? How do you know it's used or not?
